# A word that describe excitability due to youth

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describe, with some specificity, the tendency for a person to be easily excited and interested by something due to the lack of age or experience.

Sentence:

> Weapons are one of the favourite subjects of ____ boys.

Comment: In this sentence I think the word is ***all***.

Comment: Perhaps "impressionable" or "wide-eyed" might convey some of what you're looking for.

Comment: I think 'impetuous' carries connotations of callowness, as does 'eager' (especially when paired with nouns like 'youths'). In your particular example, 'boys' itself let's the reader know your keen individuals are young, so I don't think the adjective needs to do *all* the lifting to get your meaning across.

Answer (score 1):

**rambunctious**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rambunctious)

> 1. difficult to control or handle; wildly boisterous:
>      *a rambunctious child.*

[wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rambunctious)

> Energetic, noisy, boisterous and difficult to control. 
>   *The kids are being especially rambunctious today.*

**exuberant**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/exuberant)

> 1. effusively and almost uninhibitedly enthusiastic;

its noun form *exuberance* is usually used as in *childhood exuberance*

Answer (score 1):

> Weapons are one of the favourite subjects of ***juvenile*** boys.

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/juvenile):

> [**juvenile**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/juvenile) *adjective*
>
> 1 a :  physiologically immature or undeveloped :  young
>
> 2 :  of, relating to,
> characteristic of, or suitable for children or young people
>
> 3 :  reflecting psychological or intellectual immaturity :
> childish

Also, ***youthful***:

> Weapons are one of the favourite subjects of ***youthful*** boys.

From [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/youthful):

> **[youthful](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/youthful)** *adjective*
>
> Full Definition of *youthful*:
>
> 1 :  of, relating to, or
> characteristic of youth
>
> 2 :  being young and
> not yet mature
>
> 3 :  marked by or possessing youth

Answer (score 0):

An option with slightly more emphasis on the lack of experience than on the excitability:
**[Unseasoned](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unseasoned)**

> **unseasoned** 
> /ʌnˈsiːzənd/ adjective 
>   1. (of persons) not sufficiently experienced: unseasoned troops
>   
> 2. not matured or seasoned: unseasoned timber
>   Examples: 
>  *[regiments were mostly composed of draughts from various other corps,
>   consisting principally of old men, and unseasoned boys](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3KRfAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA330&lpg=PA330&dq=%22unseasoned%20boys%22&source=bl&ots=_0OMR_z5YT&sig=i2a5Y2ntJQ6N5qmMqAJhmWWn7tw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL6ZvZoZvPAhXsL8AKHWKgDcwQ6AEILTAH)*
>  *[only amateurs could play slam tournaments, like little, unseasoned boys](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=15&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiFwfmBo5vPAhVkB8AKHZUBDQQ4ChAWCCkwBA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tennis4you.com%2Ffeatured%2520articles%2Farchive%2Farticle-008.htm&usg=AFQjCNEr0t4dFIhAIhC-oCnwGdFBtJp51A&bvm=bv.133178914,d.ZGg)*

Comment: Not sure this really works in the example sentence.

Comment: You might be right, can you expand in why not? The word is most often used in a martial or sporting context, but can be used outside of those. The example sentence only gives limited context but does refer to 'weapons', so martial may well be in scope. None of the answers given address all of the elements requested, most focusing on the aspect youth or excitability.

Comment: I think because "unseasoned" primarily refers to the lack of experience, but does nothing to suggest excitement or interest.  The question suggests that enthusiasm is very important, and "unseasoned" is too neutral.

Comment: You don't think the same limitation applies to all of the answers in that none of them suggest **all** the elements posed in the question?